# How do I use the same widget within kv file

Tags: kivy, spinner, kivy-language

I would like to define the form of a widget (in this case a spinner) just once in the kv file, but use it from multiple screens. Different input screens (menu1, etc) are called from other screens, many of them have spinners that I want to look identical. In this case I am using the simple spinner "color_spin."

I open menu1 from another window and this seems to work:

```
<menu1>:
    name: "menu1"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Properties"
            size_hint: 0.6,0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2,"top":1}
        Spinner:
            id: color
            size_hint_max_y: 50
            text: 'Color'
            values: 'White','Purple','Blue','Green','Yellow','Orange','Red','Black','Grey'
            # Callback
            on_text: [do my thing]
```

But I would like to have only 1 "color_spin" called from many different menus, so I would like to do something like this:

```
<menu1>:
    name: "menu1"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Properties"
            size_hint: 0.6,0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2,"top":1}
        Spinner:
            [use spinner "color_spin", but how?]

<color_spin>:
    Spinner:
        id: color
        size_hint_max_y: 50
        text: 'Color'
        values: 'White','Purple','Blue','Green','Yellow','Orange','Red','Black','Grey'
        # Callback
        on_text: [do my thing]
```

I am very new to kivy so I appreciate any input you can give.

Comment: Have a look at [dynamic classes](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) in `kv`.

Answer (score 0):

First create your `ColorSpinner`:

```py
<ColorSpinner@Spinner>:
    size_hint_max_y: 50
    text: 'Color'
    values: 'White','Purple','Blue','Green','Yellow','Orange','Red','Black','Grey'
```

and then add it wherever you like:

```py
<menu1>:
    name: "menu1"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Label:
            text: "Properties"
            size_hint: 0.6,0.2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.2,"top":1}
        ColorSpinner:
            id: menu1_color
            # Callback
            on_text: [do my thing]

<color_spin>:
    ColorSpinner:
        id: color
        # Callback
        on_text: [do my thing]
```

Comment: This works good. However, when I open the spinner a second time the previous values are retained. Initially the spinner text is the value of "text" in <ColorSpinner@Spinner> (i.d. "Color" in the example). I would like it to be "Color" every time it opens. Essentially, I would like a new//clean instance of ColorSpinner every time I call it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The spinner changes its text when there is a new selected value. ... And that's the point of using a Spinner. You can use instead a button, that creates a dropdown menu. My answer is answering your original question. For another question, please open a new thread. That way it is more clear to the people that come here for a specific answer.

Comment: @WesKitlasten If you found my answer helpful, then you might consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), so other people see it too.. ;o)